# JOIN with or on either of 2 columns returns duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have 3 tables A, B and C. The column `b_id` on table **C** is `nullable` which is why I'm trying to make a join on **either** of 2 columns, however my query produces 4 rows and returns duplicates.

**Table A**

```
| id |
|----|
| 1  |
```

**Table B**

```
| id | a_id |
|----|------|
| 1  | 1    |
| 2  | 1    |
```

**Table C**

```
| id | a_id | b_id |
|----|------|------|
| 7  | 1    | 1    |
| 8  | 1    | 2    |
```

The following `INNER JOIN` query with an `or` produces duplicates (4 results) because of the `B` table.

```sql
select
  C.*
from
  A
  join B on (A.id = B.a_id)
  join C on (
    A.id = C.a_id
    or B.id = C.b_id
  )
where
  A.id = 1;
```

This query however with a `CTE` does produce the result I want.

```sql
with cte as (
  select
    A.id as a_id,
    B.id as b_id
  from A
    join B on (A.id = B.a_id)
  where A.id = 1
)
select *
from C
where
  C.a_id in (
    select
      a_id
    from
      cte
  )
  or C.b_id in (
    select
      b_id
    from
      cte
  );
```

Is there a simpler/cleaner way to write this query?

Comment: Show the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want columns from C how about this?

```
select c.*
from c
where c.a_id = 1 or
      exists (select 1
              from b
              where c.b_id = b.id and b.a_id = 1
             );
```

Comment: Exactly that but it needs a `null` check on `c.a_id`, so `where (c.a_id is null or c.a_id = 1) or exists(...)`